# CSS Flickering with jquery load function()

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I've hunted for an answer but not been able to find one, I am loading an HTML page using the jquery load() function, in the html it loads there is also a stylesheet, but the content is loading before the stylesheet causing un-formatted content to be shown causing a flocker like effect.

How can I get around this?

```
$('#mainbody').load("test.html", function(){
    $jq('#mainbody a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $jq(this).attr('href');
        if(url != "#"){
            loadurl($jq(this).attr('href'));
        }
    });
});
```

test.html (just keep adding the paragraph to the page to replicate it)

```
<link href="css/loginform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<h2>Login</h2>
Unauthorised access, including unsuccessful attempts to access privileged information, constitutes an offense under the Computer Misuse Act 1990.  This Network is protected by a Security System and logs will be used as evidence in court. If you are not an authorised user do not attempt to proceed beyond this point.
<p>line</p>
<p>line</p>
<p>line</p>
<p>line</p>
<p>line</p>
<p>line</p>
```

The css could be anything but something like this (might need to add more the bloat it out

```css
h2 {
    padding: 0; margin: 0; color: #ebebeb; font: bold 44px "Calibri", Arial;
}
```

Comment: Is this only, when you load the html from an extern html file? What happens, when you embed the html inside the javascript, and then ``$('#mainbody').append('<h2>Login</h2>Unaut...');``?

Comment: @23tux unsure but the method you suggest wouldn't work as it will in time load php scripts that could hold a lot of "random" data

Comment: I wanted to figure out, if the flicker depends on some part of the async loading, or if it is a main problem with appending content to your page

Answer (score 0):

hide the #mainbody div until items have loaded.

```
var $main_body = $('#mainbody');
$main_body.load("test.html", function(){
    $main_body.show();
    $jq('#mainbody a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $jq(this).attr('href');
        if (url != "#"){
            loadurl($jq(this).attr('href'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: tried it and it still flickers as the css is loaded as part of the test.html

Comment: maybe you can add a delay to showing of the content but then again 1 sec might not be enough if the person has a terrible connection

Comment: yeah thats the only problem its adding to the appearance that the site is slow :(  I have a solution which I don't like but looks like I have no other choice at the moment. :(